# strtod definition and type of passed pointer

Tags: c, strtod

From definition `double strtod ( const char * str, char ** endptr );`

C reference sites provide an example for that mighty function:

```
char szOrbits[] = "365.24 29.53";
char * pEnd;
double d1, d2;
d1 = strtod (szOrbits,&pEnd);
d2 = strtod (pEnd,NULL);
```

If `endptr` should be of type `char **` why is `char *pEnd` used here ? And not `char **pEnd` ?

Comment: Look up pass-by-reference in C. That's what it does.

Comment: `endptr` is of type `char**` so that the function could modify the `char*` it points to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `pEnd` is `char *`. The type of `&pEnd` is `char **`.

C passes arguments to functions by value, so to modify a pointer you need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

You could define a `char **` directly but you would need to initialize it to a `char *` as the idea is that `strtod` is modifying a `char *`.

Like:

```
char *q;
char **p = &q;

d1 = strtod (szOrbits, p);
```

Obviously the intermediate `p` pointer is not necessary and you can use `&q` directly.

Comment: +1 nice explanation of a classic misunderstanding of pointers/

Answer (score 2):

`pEnd` is a `char*`, as you've observed. The first example call to `strtod()` passes `&pEnd` as the second argument. `&pEnd` is the address of `pEnd`, and is therefore of type `char**`.